# how to scheduled dynamics tasks in java

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I need to schedule multiple tasks in the spring boot java project and to do task settings by bringing the value of the task execution time from a database and updating the scheduled appointment during runtime in my program.

Clarification of use case, I have a Rest API, It requires me to make a new schedule making a POST request on the endpoint 
the request includes in the body of the necessary information about this schedule, such as the time of the task and the job to be performed, and after making the request, the task is scheduled in my program and executed at its appointed time

I looked at some technology that provides solutions to make his schedules like spring schedule and Quartz, But I cannot create a custom schedule and add it to the scheduling queue in the system, according to the case I mentioned

What technologies should I use for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the answer in your question. Just creat a scheduler and **call the same methods that your api calls internally**.   [example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks)

Comment: thanks, chathura , but can you explain the idea more